# How is the weekly inflation calculated?

Tags: stellar-laboratory, inflation

Is it based on daily average of just a snapshot of Monday 11:59 UTC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inflation occurs when somebody (anybody) transacts the Inflation Operation and it has been at least 1 week since the last successful Inflation Operation. The calculations are performed at that time.

The inflation pool is `(number of lumens in existence)*(weekly inflation rate) + fee pool`

This amount is shared pro-rata amongst all accounts which meet the minimum voting threshold. That is, the cumulative amount of lumens held by accounts voting for an account must exceed `(number of lumens in existence)*.0005`.

Full details of this process are documented in the [Stellar dev guide](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/inflation.html#how-inflation-voting-works).

Outside of the network, inflation pools such as [lumenaut](https://pool.lumenaut.net/) or [xlmpool](https://xlmpool.com/) will redistribute their inflation award to voting accounts per their own rules.