# Inflation calculation rule

Tags: inflation

What is the weekly inflation reward calculation rule? Is the reward calculated by the XLM owned by the bonus pool or calculated by the XLM owned by the current account? If I had 100XLM when voting for stellarpool, and the transaction was made after the vote, the XLM was reduced to 40. At this time, the number of votes in the entire stellarpool will be affected? Will it be reduced? Will my value for getting inflation rewards be reduced?

Comment: Have you checked out this answer? https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/2389/1552

Answer (score 1):

If you had 100 lumens when you set your inflation destination, then sent 40 lumens to a different address, the 'weight' of your vote would change and the amount of inflation you receive would be affected as well.

All calculations are done at the time the [Inflation Operation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#inflation) is run.